# IE8 Not showing divs with floats

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I've created an article looking page, which works on all browsers except IE8-... Which would be okay if this wasn't specifically aimed at IE using machines... The worst part is that I actually had this working at one point, but I sort of lost all my work when messing around with some cables under my desk, I really should've saved

Below is the way i'd like it to look like across all browsers(so far it only looks like this for everything aside from IE)
[image: Working image]

And this is what it looks like on IE...

[image: Not working]

This is the current CSS, I couldn't see anything that springs to mind

```
div.GalleryColumn {display: inline; height: 320px; width: 95%; overflow: auto; display: inline;}

div.GalleryColumn.ColumnContent {width: 65%; max-height: 320px; margin-top: 25px; }
div.GalleryColumn.ColumnContent:nth-child(odd) {float: right;}
div.GalleryColumn.ColumnContent:nth-child(even) {float: left;  text-align: right;}

div.GalleryColumn.ColumnImage {width: 25%; height: 320px; margin-top: 25px;}
div.GalleryColumn.ColumnImage:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
div.GalleryColumn.ColumnImage:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: -10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: -10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
}
```

I don't know if any of this helps, I'm just confused because I had it working at one point, but now I've forgotten how to fix it at all

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=float  seems that IE8 don't support float ..

Comment: That would make a lot of sense... Now I'm super confused as to how i managed to get it working before. I think I had it so that all images were on the right and text on the left because IE8 does not  support div:nth-child()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.GalleryColumn.ColumnContent {float: left; width: 65%; max-height: 320px; margin-top: 25px; }

div.GalleryColumn.ColumnImage {float: right; width: 25%; height: 320px; margin-top: 25px;}
```

This is how I had it the last time! As IE8 doesn't support :nth-child() [Thanks for @Turi for reminding] I had it simply default to having text on one side, and images on the other. If their using IE8, they probably don't want to see the "fun" alternating text/image anyway...

So now IE8 will look like this while the others still alternate

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems IE8 doesn't support the nth-child pseudo-class, so that's likely your problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Would it be pssible to add .left and .right classes to the individual elements?

Comment: I remember now! You reminded me! I had it using a default float. So where I put:

    div.GalleryColumn.ColumnImage {width: 25%; height: 320px; margin-top: 25px;}

and the same for ColumnContent, I simply defaulted where they'd float to. So when a browser, for example IE8, comes along which doesn't support nth-child(), it would simply place the text one one side, with the images on the other! It's one of those friday things!